# Swisscom S3 Dynamic Storage concurrent access

Tags: amazon-s3, parallel-processing, upload, load-testing, swisscomdev

We are experiencing problems while working with Swisscom S3 Dynamic Storage.
When making concurrent test CRUD requests in 5 and more parrallel threads, Storage service sends us randomly 403 Forbidden instead of corrent answer. While executing same requests sequentially, one-by-one, everything works ok.

Code that I am using is here below

```
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;
import com.amazonaws.util.StringInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Tutorial https://javatutorial.net/java-s3-example
 */
public class AmazonS3ManualTest {

    public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "??";
    private static String accessKey = "??";
    private static String secretKey = "??";

    @Test
    public void testOperations() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final int maxCount = 5;

        final AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = getS3Client();

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(maxCount);
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    final String FolderOne = "testFolderOne" + index;
                    final String FolderTwo = "testFolderTwo" + index;
                    final String FolderCopy = "copyFolder" + index;

                    try {
                        createFile(amazonS3Client, "/" + FolderOne + "/file.txt");
                        createFolder(amazonS3Client, FolderTwo + "/");

                        exists(amazonS3Client, FolderOne + "/file.txt");
                        exists(amazonS3Client, FolderTwo + "/");

                        copy(amazonS3Client, FolderOne + "/file.txt", FolderCopy + "/filecopy.txt");

                        delete(amazonS3Client, "/" + FolderOne);
                        delete(amazonS3Client, "/" + FolderTwo);

                        get(amazonS3Client, FolderCopy + "/filecopy.txt");
                        delete(amazonS3Client, "/" + FolderCopy + "/filecopy.txt");

                        isEmptyFolder(amazonS3Client, "/" + FolderCopy);
                        delete(amazonS3Client, "/ + FolderCopy");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (final Exception ignored) {
                }
            });
        }

        if (!latch.await(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Waiting too long for the result");
        }
    }

    private void isEmptyFolder(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String folder) {
        final ObjectListing objectListing = amazonS3Client.listObjects(BUCKET_NAME, folder);
        assert(objectListing.getObjectSummaries().isEmpty());
    }

    private void get(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String file) throws IOException {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, file);
        final S3Object object = amazonS3Client.getObject(request);
        final S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
        final String s = IOUtils.toString(objectContent);
        assert(s.length() > 0);
    }

    private void copy(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String source, String target) {
        CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, source, BUCKET_NAME, target);
        amazonS3Client.copyObject(request);
    }

    private void delete(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String path) {
        deleteRecursive(amazonS3Client, path);
    }

    private void deleteRecursive(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String path) {
        ObjectListing objects = amazonS3Client.listObjects(BUCKET_NAME, path);

        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            if (objectSummary.getKey().equals(path)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (objectSummary.getKey().endsWith("/")) {
                deleteRecursive(amazonS3Client, objectSummary.getKey());
            } else {
                amazonS3Client.deleteObject(BUCKET_NAME, objectSummary.getKey());
            }
        }

        amazonS3Client.deleteObject(BUCKET_NAME, path);
    }

    private void exists(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String folder) {
        GetObjectMetadataRequest request = new GetObjectMetadataRequest(BUCKET_NAME, folder);
        try {
            final ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = amazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(request);
            assert(objectMetadata != null);
        } catch (AmazonS3Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage().contains("404")) {
                assert(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        assert(true);
    }

    private void createFolder(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String folder) {
        final InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(0);

        amazonS3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, folder, input, metadata));
    }

    private void createFile(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String fileName) throws IOException {
        ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
        //omd.setContentType("html/text");
        omd.setHeader("filename", fileName);
        omd.setHeader("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256");

        // upload file to folder and set it to public
        final StringInputStream testFile = new StringInputStream("Test");
        final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, fileName, testFile, omd);
        amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.Private));

        testFile.close();
    }

    private AmazonS3Client getS3Client() {

        ClientConfiguration opts = new ClientConfiguration();
        opts.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");  // NOT "AWS3SignerType"
        opts.setMaxConnections(100);

        final AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey), opts);
        s3.setEndpoint("ds31s3.swisscom.com");

        return s3;
    }
}
```

Exception we are getting is here:

`com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null`

Can you please recommend, what can we do with such a situation, because it's abnormal and not scalable.

Comment: please paste the code snipped generating this error. Describe what you are doing exactly

Comment: I edited my question with code snippet I used.

Comment: I'm observing the exact same behavior. However, the problem is not raised in a immediate download call, but in very fast and continuous upload calls in chunks. Then, I also get HTTP 403 -- which is very very weird, since the object Id is created!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated new Dynamic Storage S3 and rerun test above. Now exceptions were not raising. Seems there was infra problem with previously created Storage.

Answer (score 0):

We run your snippet 80 times in a row against the S3 Dynamic Storage of Swisscom and couldn't reproduce the issue.

However there might be a timing issue when directly accessing the object after uploading it. The PUT request may be balanced to another node than the GET request. So if you immediately want to download an object after uploading it, please implement a short sleep or a retry.

Comment: Did you run this code in concurrency mode? let's say 5 parrallel threads.

Comment: Thanks for running my code snippet. It's really weird that it's not reproducable on your side. Did you run in concurrent mode? let's say 5 parrallel threads. I did run tests once more and I am always gettings this exceptions. `So if you immediately want to download an object after uploading it, please implement a short sleep or a retry` - does this statement says that your Storage is not yet cloud ready ?

Comment: The official answer is `please implement a short sleep or a retry`? Really? This is simply unacceptable in my humble opinion. Then, I would prefer to pay Amazon S3. :-(